# Prove $\sqrt{ \frac{2x^2 - 2x + 1}{2} } \geq \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}$ for $0 < x < 1$

Tags: inequality

I stumbled upon this question  while doing practice inequalities questions, and I do not know how to start...

Problem: Prove that

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{ \frac{2x^2 - 2x + 1}{2} } \geq \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}
for $0 < x < 1$.

I thought possibly of having an intermediate equality, for example

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2x^2-2x+1}{2}}\ge\text{something}\ge\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}

where the "something" is simple, but I could not deduce anything...any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that $2x^2-2x+1=x^2+(x^2-2x+1)=x^2+(x-1)^2$, maybe you can use A.G. inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Notice that  $\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}=\sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^2} \ge \sqrt{(\frac{x+1-x}{2})^2}=\frac12$ and 
$\frac{1}{x+\frac1x}\le \frac{1}{2x\frac1x}=\frac12$

Answer (score 0):

This inequality is true for all $x>0$. Indeed$,$ 
$$ \frac{(x+\frac{1}{x})^2(2x^2-2x+1)}{2}-1$$

$$={\frac {2 \ \left( 2\ x-1 \right) ^{2}{x}^{2}+ \left( x-1
 \right) ^{4} \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}+{x}^{2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}
 \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}{2{x}^{2}}} \geqq 0$$